# Microsoft Graph-API (graph.microsoft.com/v1.0) returns duplicate or non existing mails

Tags: python, email, python-requests, microsoft-graph-api, office365

I have an Outlook account and I see **one Mail** in my inbox folder. I can somehow also expand this mail in the overview which will expand it to two entries. (Probably because it was forwarded once and moved into Archive folder and then back to inbox).
But I cannot delete one of them, I can just delete it completely.

Now, when I fetch the mails via Graph-API, then i get a result of **61 mails** with almost the same uuid.

They differ only at the 5th character from behind. And that letter is ascending.

> Example uuid: *.....AAJokmf**S**AAA=*
>
> and the next is: *.....AAJokmf**T**AAA=*
>
> and so on.

I don´t understand why it is like that and I want to have only the one mail returned for my query, which I also see in Outlook Online.

In theory it would be possible to filter the "same" mails based on the common part of the uuid, as it is obviously not exactly the same, but almost. But then I should at least understand, how the uuid is defined and why I am getting those duplicates.

My query looks like this (Python):

```
# init
request = f"grant_type=password&client_id={oauth_client_id}&username={user}&scope=user.read%20openid%20profile%20offline_access&password=" + \
              requests.utils.quote(password)
user_result = requests.post(
    f"https://login.microsoftonline.com/{oauth_tenant_id}/oauth2/v2.0/token", data=request)
if user_result.status_code >= 300 or not 'access_token' in user_result.json():
    error_msg = f"MailConnection.__enter__ failed with error:  {json.loads(user_result.content)['error']} : {json.loads(user_result.content)['error_description']}"
    print(error_msg)
    raise Exception(error_msg)
access_token = user_result.json()['access_token']


# send
endpoint = f'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{user}/mailFolders'
mailfolders = requests.get(endpoint,
                headers={'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + access_token})
mailfolders = json.loads(mailfolders.text)
print(mailfolders)
src_folder = 'inbox'

src_folder_param = list(filter(lambda folder: folder['displayName'] == src_folder, mailfolders['value'] ))
endpoint = f'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{user}/mailFolders/{src_folder_param[0]["id"]}/messages?$top=100'

res = requests.get(endpoint, headers={'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + access_token})

resultmails = json.loads(res.text)
for mail in resultmails['value']:
    print(mail)

print(len(resultmails['value'])) # why it is 61? there is only one mail in inbox
```

Anybody knows how to resolve this? Help would be really appreciated.

Comment: Could you check if all those emails have the same conversationId?

Comment: I checked again and it is in fact 61 equal mails, when there is only one. The conversationId, conversationIndex, parentFolderId, internetMesssageId, sentDateTime is exactly the same. The webLink also differs by one character.

Comment: Maybe your Outlook client is grouping emails by conversation, so it can looks like a one email, not sure.

Comment: I am able to expand the mail in the view of Outlook but then I see two connected entries (not 61) from which I cannot delete any separately. But thanks to your suggestion now I integrated a cleanup step, where I compare the conversationId and conversationIndex and if both are the same, then I delete the duplicates via Graph API rest call. Deleting this way worked and I integrate the cleanup step into my read mail function now. The root cause is still unclear, but this is a solution which will work.